# How to read multiple parameters from a json file in Protractor jasmine?

Tags: jasmine, protractor, parameterization

Login.js file

```
'use strict';
var testData = require('./testdata.json');
describe('LoginPage', function() {

var loginData = require('./testdata.json');

it("data.description", function () {

browser.get("http://custemea3.imshealth.com/GlobalDashboard/qaconsole");
browser.driver.sleep(8000);
browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/undefined/div/ims-
form/div[2]/div/div[2]/dynamic-
component/form/div[1]/div[1]/input')).sendKeys(testData[0].username);

browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/undefined/div/ims-
form/div[2]/div/div[2]/dynamic-
component/form/div[1]/div[2]/input')).sendKeys(testData[0].passwordField); 
browser.driver.sleep(4000);
browser.driver.findElement(by.className('btn btn-success')).click();

browser.driver.sleep(8000);
  });
});
```

I wrote the above code to read a pair of parameters from a json file. But, I am unable to read the parameters when I try to read multiple pairs of parameters like below:

testdata.json file

```
[
{
 "username":"ims",
 "passwordField":"123"
},

{
 "username":"ims",
 "passwordField":"ims"
}
]
```

since I am new to protractor I don't know how to modify my code to read multiple parameters. I tried foreach using arrays but it didn't work. Please help me out!

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: For the above code, it only runs once and stops. I am unable to run it in a loop.